# Custom Segue with CollectionView for iPad

Tags: ios6, uistoryboardsegue, uicollectionview, collectionview

I have an iPad App I am working on. I have a UICollectionViewController with images displayed in the Cell.

On the MainViewController I placed a ContainerView that segues to a UIViewController that has a UIImageView.

This all (Above) works fine.

I want to set things up so I have a Custom Segue from the CellViewController to the UIViewController housing the UIImageView. I want this UIImageView to change based on the Image I select from the Cells displayed in the CollectionView

Can I create a Custom Segue to do this? I can't get any of the other segues to work because they are for SplitViews or Popovers, or Pushes.